# Jinja2 range for loop - 2 variables in 1 loop

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

Im using jinja2 and im having a hardtime setting the idx variable into a forloop. It seems like Jinja is saying that idx is a key in the data record. Is there a way to set that the idx will be considered as a changing variable in a loop and not as a key. Thanks you

UPDATE

I only need to loop the index 1 - 6 since the index 0 in data is used somewhere else

**How to do this Code in Python to Jinja2**

```
for idx in range(1,7):
    print(report_rec.soundings.0.fuel_tank.idx.tank_no)
    print(report_rec.soundings.0.fuel_tank.idx.length)
    print(report_rec.soundings.0.fuel_tank.idx.volume)
```

**Data Example**

```
'soundings': [{
    'pkey': '5f17a3f7c511d0b094326274',
    'fuel_tank': [{
        'tank_no': '1',
        'length': '1',
        'volume': 1.0,
    }, {
        'tank_no': '2',
        'length': '2',
        'volume': 2.0,
    }, {
        'tank_no': '3',
        'length': '3',
        'volume': 3.0,
    }, {
        'tank_no': '4',
        'length': '4',
        'volume': 4.0,
    }, {
        'tank_no': '5',
        'length': '5',
        'volume': 5.0,
    }, {
        'tank_no': '6',
        'length': '6',
        'volume': 6.0,
    }, {
        'tank_no': '7',
        'length': '7',
        'volume': 7.0,
    }]
```

**This is my HTML CODE**

```
{% for idx in range(1,7) %}
    <tr>
      <td>Tank No</td>
      <td><input name="ft_tank_{{idx}}" type="text" value="{{ report_rec.soundings.0.fuel_tank.idx.tank_no }}"></td>
      <td>CM</td>
      <td><input name="ft_length_{{idx}}" type="text" value="{{ report_rec.soundings.0.fuel_tank.idx.length }}"></td>
      <td>Volume(ltr)</td>
      <td><input name="ft_volume_{{idx}}" type="text"value="{{ report_rec.soundings.0.fuel_tank.idx.volume }}" ></td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that structure,

```
{% for tank in report_rec.soundings.0 %}
    {{ tank.tank_no }}
    ... etc.
{% endfor %}
```

seems like it would work better as a way to iterate through the tanks.

If you want to ignore the first tank, you can take advantage of the special `loop` variable that Jinja2 provides. (See [here](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#for))

```
{% for tank in report_rec.soundings.0 %}
    {% if loop.index0 > 0 %}
        {{ tank.tank_no }}
        ... etc.
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Oh Im sorry. I forgot to mention I need only to loop the index 1 to 6. The index 0 is used somewhere else.

Comment: The special `loop` variable might be of use. See above.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `{{ loop.index }}` to get the index in the for loop.